# 2nd order distribution differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Denote by $f(x)$ a quadratic polynomial with coeffitients $a, b, c$:
$$ f(x) = ax^2 + bx+ c$$
And let's look at distribution differential equation
$$f \left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\right) y =\text{p.v.} \dfrac{1}{x}$$
Or in another form
$$a\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} + b\dfrac{dy}{dx} + cy = \text{p.v.} \dfrac{1}{x}$$
Where the distribution $\text{p.v.} \dfrac{1}{x}$ act's in the following way
$$(\text{p.v.} \dfrac{1}{x} , \psi ) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\psi(x) - \psi(0)}{x} dx$$
Is there any way to solve this equations? I have tryid it in simple case, where $f(x)$ hase 2 real roots, but i failed, any help and links will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be some distribution, e.g. $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}$ and consider the differential equation ("d.e.")
$$
ay'' + by' + cy = u.
$$

Let $r=r_1,r_2$ be the two (possible equal) roots of $ar^2+br+c.$ Then we have
$$
ay'' + by' + cy = (D-r_1)(D-r_2)y,
$$
where $D$ is the differentiation operator, $Df=f'.$

Thus the d.e. can be written
$$
(D-r_1)(D-r_2)y = u.
$$

Now multiply the equation with $e^{-r_1 x}$:
$$
e^{-r_1 x} (D-r_1)(D-r_2)y = e^{-r_1 x} u.
$$

The left hand side can then be rewritten:
$$
D(e^{-r_1 x}(D-r_2)y) = e^{-r_1 x} u.
$$

Taking antiderivative gives
$$
e^{-r_1 x}(D-r_2)y = \int e^{-r_1 x} u \, dx
$$
so
$$
(D-r_2)y = e^{r_1 x} \int e^{-r_1 x} u \, dx.
$$

There is always a distribution $U$ such that $U'=e^{-r_1 x} u$ but it can be impossible to write in an explicit form. I think that is the case when $u=\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}.$

Anyway, to solve for $y,$ just repeat what we did: multiply with $e^{-r_2 x}$ and rewrite $e^{-r_2 x}(D-r_2)$ as $D(e^{-r_2 x}\cdots),$ take antiderivative and multiply with $e^{-r_2 x}.$

Comment: I suppose it's not always true that there is always a distribution $U$ such that $U′=e^{−r1x}u$, it seems that it depends on the space where the distribution acts. By the way, it's very interesting fact, is there any links how to prove this?

Comment: I'm referring to $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ for which the space of test functions is $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}).$

Comment: [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592344/prove-that-a-distribution-has-its-primitive-distribution)